# How come one type of DC motor could have different resistances?

Tags: motor, dc-motor, stepper-motor

Looking at some DC motors, a single type could have a range of resistances:

[image]

It appears that lower resistance results in higher pull-in torque. If that's the only change, wouldn't a low resistance motor always be desirable? Why would one want a high resistance, low torque motor over a low resistance, high torque one?

Any thought appreciated.

Comment: That datasheet *lists* the torque values for each motor (pull-in torque), can't you go off that? Just be aware, that stepper motors (and that's exactly what these are) don't spin is you apply a DC voltage to them. Stepper motors require a bit of driver smarts or an AC voltage (two usually, 90 degrees offset from each other)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a 'DC' motor, that's a stepper motor. Check out the 'step angle' and 'pulses per second (PPS)' columns.

The current taken at the rated voltage is inversely proportional to resistance. You get more torque for more current and therefore power consumption.

Changing the thickness of wire that the motor stator is wound from (which is the difference between these various models) is a cheap way for the manufacturer to provide a range of power and torque options with the same basic design of motor.

To choose the motor for you, decide on your minimum torque, then choose the lowest power consumption motor that will deliver it.

If you chose a motor, but it turned out late in the product development that you'd underestimated the torque needed, then you could move up to the next more powerful motor very easily, without a mechanical redesign, or even reduce the power consumption if you found you'd been too generous to start with. A common pattern is simply to prototype with the most powerful option, then trim consumption down later once you have several real systems to test.

Comment: To choose the lowest torque motor, does that mean choosing the motor with the highest resistance?

Comment: If you can read this, then you can read the data sheet you posted. Are you having a problem with the bottom two rows that have different resistance, but the same torque? That may be a min figure for torque, limited by their test methods, rather than the actual typical motor performance. The three rows above those two have the same (higher) torque figure as well. You may have to learn to 'read between the lines' of a data sheet.